# Factorisation of large composite number given a factor

Tags: factoring

I have a sneak feeling that for $n\geq2$ we have that $2^{2^n}+1$ is a factor of $2^{2^{2^{n}-1}}-1$. If we say that $2^{2^{2^{n}-1}}=2^{2^n}\cdot2^k$ for some positive integer $k$ then my idea was to write $$2^{2^{2^{n}-1}}-1=(2^{2^n}+1)(2^k+\dots-1)$$ but I'm having trouble finding the explicit form this second bracket on the right hand side.

I'm welcome to any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general result is that $(a-b)|(a^m-b^m)$ which you can prove by summing a geometric series with ratio $\frac ab$.  Note that $\left(2^{2^n}+1\right)\left(2^{2^n}-1\right)=2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ so apply the general result with $a=2^{2^{n+1}}, b=1, m=\frac {2^{2^{n-1}}}{2^{n+1}}$.  $m$ will be an integer if $2^{n-1} \ge n+1$, which is true for $n \ge 3$.  I have checked the case $n=2$ separately, giving $17|255$.

Comment: I think you misplaced the second $-1$. It's subtracted from the number itself, not from the exponent.

Comment: @joriki:  I just noticed that.  It works for $n=2,3$

Comment: It also works for $n=4$ – I clicked "More digits" until I got all $\sim10000$ digits to make sure it was an integer :-D.

Comment: @joriki:  I was going to, then thought to check the scientific notation version against the first digits of the exact result.  They can only match if the denominator is (very close to) a power of $10$.